# Run mongodb with election in two datacenters

Tags: mongodb, high-availability

I have read the mongoDB documentation but it don't really solve my problem.

Is there a way to run mongoDB in two datacenteres (DC) and make the a primary available if one DC gets lost.

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/) of MongoDB said:

> - Two data centers: two members to Data Center 1 and one member to Data Center 2. If one of the members of the replica set is an arbiter, distribute the arbiter to Data Center 1 with a data-bearing member.
>
>   - If Data Center 1 goes down, the replica set becomes read-only.
>   - If Data Center 2 goes down, the replica set remains writeable as the members in Data Center 1 can hold an election.

But I need to get the MongoDB writeable when DC1 goes down too. Is there any possibllity to get this work.

Our software which we use to monitor the services is able to react to the lost of one DC. So it might be possible to start an arbiter on DC2 when DC1 goes down. If DC1 comes back online we can shut down the arbiter at DC2 and restart the arbiter at DC1.

The question is, will this work?

I know it would be nicer to run all of this on three DCs but our customer only has two.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a setup like so:

[image]

You get to decide which datacenter holds the original primary node, and you can have more secondaries if you desire.

Then, set your secondary nodes in DC2 to have a higher priority than the ones in DC1.

This way, when the primary becomes unavailable, wither from a failure in the database server, or a full DC outage, the next primary will be chosen in DC2.

*Also, you don't need (or want) an arbiter, they are advised against, which is discussed in more detail why in the MongoDB University course: Cluster Administration.*

**Edit:** Not sure on your full requirements but have you also seen: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-geographically-distributed-replica-set/

Comment: Thanks for your advices. Unfortunately I will have to wait now for my V-Servers to get this tested.

Comment: Hey I'm very sorry about my delayed answer. 
I have tested your suggestion but it doesn't work as expected. The instance with the highest priority is choosen automaticly as PRIMARY. But if the DC with the primary turns of no new primary is choosen. Because there is no third voting member,

Comment: @dominic hi, not a problem - understood, this is due to an even number of voters, you could either add a third member to each DC, or if you’re concerned about space, you can revoke voting rights from a member of the DC so that only one of the nodes become primary from it’s own election... but that isn’t really keeping to HA standards... so the alternative (which I previously advised against) is to add an arbiter purely for voting purposes and to hold no data. In my opinion, adding a 3rd member to each DC is better approach.